# How to align images using NextGen singlepic?

Tags: html, css

When using NextGen singlepic I cannot vertically and horizontally align images to the center using CSS.

The layout of the images I want to achieve is almost perfect. Please see https://rolandgeiger.com/al-capone/ for an example (lower two images). The responsive layout is fine, but I would like to align the images vertically and horizontally to the center. 
In Firefox the images are aligned to the top left. 
In Chrome the images are aligned to the top center.

HTML:

> [lgc_column grid="50" tablet_grid="100" mobile_grid="100" last="false"  > equal_heights=”false”]
>      
>   0px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"
>   src="https://rolandgeiger.com/wp-content/gallery/blog-al-capone/roland-
>   geiger-stuttgart-fotograf-201512131722000065.jpg" alt="roland-geiger-
>   stuttgart-fotograf-201512131722000065">
>   [/lgc_column]
>
> [lgc_column grid="50" tablet_grid="100" mobile_grid="100" last="true" 
>   equal_heights=”false”]
>      
>   0px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"
>   src="https://rolandgeiger.com/wp-content/gallery/blog-al-capone/roland-
>   geiger-stuttgart-fotograf-201512131724000076.jpg" alt="roland-geiger-
>   stuttgart-fotograf-201512131724000076">
>   [/lgc_column]

CSS:

> .lgc-column
>   {
>       vertical-align:middle;
>   }

I'm new to CSS. But I hope you can help me aligning the images to the center in Firefox and Chrome! :-)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't know how to format the source code correctly...?!

Comment: Just delete those ">", highlight the code and click code icon in the editor.

Comment: If I'm doing that, it tells me "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." and the output is:
[lgc_column grid="50" tablet_grid="100" mobile_grid="100" last="false" equal_heights=”false”] [/lgc_column]

[lgc_column grid="50" tablet_grid="100" mobile_grid="100" last="true" equal_heights=”false”] [/lgc_column]

CSS: .lgc-column
{
vertical-align:middle;
}